# trouble using keyframes to animate a float value (in animation nodes)

Tags: animation-nodes

Am learning animation nodes.

Within animation nodes, I would like to use keyframes to animate the value of a float number, but the keyframes are not having any effect.

To try this I right click on the float value and first 'add to keying set' then 'add keyframe'

it seems to work because no errors are reported and the value changes color.

But when I play the animation the keyframe seems to have no effect.   Screenshot below shows the nodes and my attempt to enter the keyframe.  (the idea is the float number then is used to place an object at a location).

Any suggestions to make the keyframe actually work are most welcome.

thanks,
Matt

[image]

[image: nodes]

Comment: Hm. Not sure if you can animate values INSIDE of Animation Nodes. 

You could just add an empty to your scene, then keyframe the empty X location (a float), then use AN object transform input to use the value from the empty

Comment: Thanks that worked!!   I had the idea you could animate inside the nodes because it seems to be available to do that on the right-click menu, and the color changes after you add the keyframe, and so thought maybe there was way.  But the keyframe markers never appeared on the timeline.  The method you suggested is a great solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Delay Time` and `Animate Float` node in this case.

[image]

**Another Method:**

Create an custom property to a object(in this example Cube) and keyframe the value. then access it's value inside AN.
You can use `Object Attribute Input` node to do this.

[image]

Comment: Can you detail why this works?

Comment: thanks and that is a good suggestion  - I tried delay time and animate float - and yes it works but, unless i'm missing some options, i wasn't able to design enough control into the system to do what I wanted.  I need to animate a float variable to increase and decrease in various profiles - which are well suited for keyframes - but with the blocks available within AN i could only add a delay offset and choose among a few monotonic profiles (eg linear, segments of sines, etc).

Comment: @MattG I have added another method.